# Dynamic number of attributes in PubSub publish() function for python client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish messages to the [Pub/Sub service on the Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher) using a Python publisher client.

### Problem Description:

I have an excel file with multiple sheets. Each sheet has a different number of columns. For each of the sheets, I need to publish each row as a separate message to the PubSub service on the cloud.

For a sheet having 4 columns, I used the following steps referring to the sample code in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher):

- Create an object called `publisher` from the `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()` class
- Use the `publisher.publish()` method for sending the data to my topic on the cloud
- In the arguments for the `publish()` method, I have considered each column as an attribute in the message as shown in the following line of code (this line would be for publishing from one row):

  ```
  future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, column1 = columnvalue1 , column2 = columnvalue2)
  ```

### Question:

In the program I am writing, I wish to publish messages from the sheet that the user specifies. As different sheets have different number of columns, I wish to know if there is any method to dynamically change the number of arguments in the `publish()` function depending on the number of columns in that particular sheet?

### My attempt;

I tried to use a brute force approach using if-else statements. For an example where there are three sheets with 2,3 and 4 columns respectively; I read the specified sheet from the Excel file into a pandas dataframe. I then loop through each row and publish the contents as follows:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    # <All other relevant code and operations>
 
    if (args.sheet == 'Sheet1'):
           future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, column1 = columnvalue1 , column2 = columnvalue2)
    elif (args.sheet == 'Sheet2'):
           future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, column1 = columnvalue1 , column2 = columnvalue2, column3 = columnvalue3) 
    elif (args.sheet == 'Sheet3'):
           future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, column1 = columnvalue1 , column2 = columnvalue2, column3 = columnvalue3, column4 = columnvalue4) 

    # <rest of the code>
```

This approach works; but as the number of sheets increase, it becomes a tedious task to keep adding more `elif` conditions.

Is there any better alternative to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is 2 things:

1. You need to know for which sheet you need which attributes. You can define this in the format that you want, YAML or JSON is great for this

```
{
 "sheet1": ["column1", "column2"],
 "sheet2": ["column1", "column2", "column3"],
 "sheet3": ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"],
}
```

2. Then you need to build dynamically the attributes list to push them with the message. You need to have a look to the publish method definition

> def publish(
> self, topic, data, ordering_key="", retry=gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT, **attrs
> ):

And the docstring

> attrs (Mapping[str, str]): A dictionary of attributes to be sent as metadata. (These may be text strings or byte strings.)

So, now, according with the sheet, you need to build a dictionary and pass it to the publish method

```
    dictionary={'column1':'columnvalue1','column2':'columnvalue2'}

    publisher.publish(topic_path, data,**dictionary)
```

You have to key parts. Now some algorithm to browse your sheet, get the value, build the dict according with the sheet number and definition. And that's all

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!

Comment: Did this work ? when I try and pass a dictionary as attributes I get a TypeError: All attributes being published to Pub/Sub must be sent as text strings. Then when looking at the client.py where it fails the publishing method only takes string or bytes, to me it looks like you need to separate each attribute you send. https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/1.2.0/_modules/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.html

Comment: In the doubt, I tested again. And yes it works. But you need to have only string attributes in your dictionnary. I tested with a numeric value `dictionary={'column1':'columnvalue1','column2':2}` and it fails with the same error that y ou @Hutch